# What Environmental Variable Sets Git Color.UI?

Tags: git, shell, version-control

Is there a Git environmental variable that dictates the `color.ui` config option?  It does not seem to be in the documentation, if there is one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, unlike some other settings, there is no environmental variable that allows you to override the `color.ui` config option.

The only way is to of course use the command line: `git config --global color.ui true`  You can also edit the `~/.gitconfig` file directly and add all  of these color options.  All of this info can be found [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config).  Add colors to your `~/.gitconfig` file:

```
[color]
  ui = auto
[color "branch"]
  current = yellow reverse
  local = yellow
  remote = green
[color "diff"]
  meta = yellow bold
  frag = magenta bold
  old = red bold
  new = green bold
[color "status"]
  added = yellow
  changed = green
  untracked = cyan
```

Highlight whitespace in diffs

```
[color]
  ui = true
[color "diff"]
  whitespace = red reverse
[core]
  whitespace=fix,-indent-with-non-tab,trailing-space,cr-at-eol
```

Answer (score 3):

#### `GIT_CONFIG_PARAMETERS="'color.ui=never'"`

Change *never* to *auto* or *always* if you like.

This is not a documented feature, but has been around for quite a while and is covered by the git unit tests.

Comment: I can confirm this works like a charm! Been looking for something like this for a while. So now instead of 
`git -c color.ui=always log --graph --oneline --decorate -n5`
You can keep code that runs inside awesome tools like [mani](https://manicli.com) (and causes git to not show colorized output because it is not connected to a terminal) clean by forcing color via an env var.
Thanks @doug-richardson!
@other readers: please upvote this over the config answer, since it does not answer @jonah's question.