# How to disable git colors using an environment variable?

Tags: git, vim

Is there a way to disable git colors using an environment variable?

#### Background

Normally when I run git, I want the output colorized. Therefore, my .gitconfig has:

```
[color]
        ui = auto
```

However, when running git from within a gVim terminal, the colors don't are hard to read. I would like to disable the colors only when running from a gVim terminal, and I could do this by setting an environment variable if one exists.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What Environmental Variable Sets Git Color.UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16676383/what-environmental-variable-sets-git-color-ui)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `GIT_CONFIG_PARAMETERS="'color.ui=never'"`

While I have not found documentation for this, it is covered by a [git test case here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2283e0e9af55689215afa39c03beb2315ce18e83/t/t1300-config.sh#L1299):

```
test_expect_success 'GIT_CONFIG_PARAMETERS handles old-style entries' '
    v="${SQ}key.one=foo${SQ}" &&
    v="$v  ${SQ}key.two=bar${SQ}" &&
    v="$v ${SQ}key.ambiguous=section.whatever=value${SQ}" &&
    GIT_CONFIG_PARAMETERS=$v git config --get-regexp "key.*" >actual &&
    cat >expect <<-EOF &&
    key.one foo
    key.two bar
    key.ambiguous section.whatever=value
    EOF
    test_cmp expect actual
```

Comment: The `GIT_CONFIG_PARAMETERS` env variable exists only for the testing code, so if the testing code is changed in the future, it's possible that `GIT_CONFIG_PARAMETERS` will change or be removed entirely. (There was some chatter on the Git mailing list recently about it, it's probably not going away. It looks like libgit2 added support for it a few years ago too!)

Comment: I would absolutely not rely on this being stable in any way.  We've discussed changing  the format of the data on the mailing list.  The Git testsuite does all sorts of untoward things which are not documented interfaces, and this is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply change GVim's terminal colors with `g:terminal_ansi_colors` variable, the value of which is expected to be a list of 16 hexadecimal colors, corresponding to the 16 so-called "ANSI colors":

```
let g:terminal_ansi_colors = [
    \ '#1c1c1c',
    \ '#af5f5f',
    \ '#5f875f',
    \ '#87875f',
    \ '#5f87af',
    \ '#5f5f87',
    \ '#5f8787',
    \ '#6c6c6c',
    \ '#444444',
    \ '#ff8700',
    \ '#87af87',
    \ '#ffffaf',
    \ '#8fafd7',
    \ '#8787af',
    \ '#5fafaf',
    \ '#ffffff',
    \ ]
```

The value above is taken from my colorscheme; feel free to use whatever works for you.